# Read any .txt file in the folder through bash

Tags: bash, shell

The idea is that I want to read any .txt file in a specific folder and do something. So I tried this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Read the file line by line
while read line
do
    if [ $i -ne 0 ]; then
       #do something...
    fi
done < "*.txt"
echo "Finished!"
```

I think you got my idea now. Thanks for any advice.

After doing some stuff, I want to move the file to another folder.

Comment: @TomFenech Well, there are some problems in `done < "*.txt"`. But now it's solved according to Josh's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid using `cat` unnecessarily, you could use a `for` loop:

```
for file in *.txt
do 
    while read line
    do  
        # whatever
        mv -i "$file" /some/other/place
    done < "$file"
done
```

This treats each file separately so you can perform actions on each one individually. If you wanted to move all the files to the same place, you could do that outside the loop:

```
for file in *.txt
do
    while read line
    do  
        # whatever        
    done < "$file"
done
mv -i *.txt /some/other/place
```

As suggested in the comments, I have added the `-i` switch to `mv`, which prompts before overwriting files. This is probably a good idea, especially when you are expanding a  `*` wildcard. If you would rather not be prompted, you could instead use the `-n` switch which will not overwrite any files.

Comment: After doing some staff, i want to mv the file to another folder. Can i do it at the same bash shell?

Comment: @TrueBlue yes you can, I've added it to my answer. You should edit your question if you have more information to add.

Comment: Should probably have an `-i` flag on both `mv` commands for safety.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what `$i` is in your `if` statement.. but you can read all the .txt files in a dir line by line like this:

```
while read line; do
    # your code here, eg
    echo "$line"
done < <(cat *.txt)
```

For a "specific directory" (ie not the directory you are currently in):

```
DIR=/example/dir
while read line; do
    # your code here, eg
    echo "$line"
done < <(cat "$DIR"/*.txt)
```

Comment: The question has been edited, so this approach no longer works.